# How to filter data with pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am looking to filter the Pandas Dataframe to select the data from two different types of attributes:

```
restaurants=df['restaurants'][df['restaurants']=='Español' or df['restaurants']=='Italiano']
```

But i can't use the option or for that could you give me an example of how to do it.

Comment: Use: `df[df['restaurants']=='Español' | df['restaurants']=='Italiano']`

Answer (score 1):

```
restaurants=df[(df['restaurants']=='Español') | (df['restaurants']=='Italiano')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# method1
rest_list = ['Español', 'Italiano']
cond = df['restaurants'].isin(rest_list)
restaurants = df.loc[cond,'restaurants']

# method2
cond = False
cond |= df['restaurants']=='Español'
cond |= df['restaurants']=='Italiano'
restaurants = df.loc[cond,'restaurants']
```